# Extjs Convert object to component

Tags: extjs, components, extjs5

I have a grid with tbar with one checkbox as item:

```
tbar: [ {
        boxLabel: 'field label',
        name: 'ShowEstimationConfilictsWhileReport',
        itemId: 'ShowEstimationConfilictsWhileReport',
        xtype: 'checkbox',

    }],
  initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        var myCheckbox =        me.tbar[0]; //?? get object but i want checkbox extjs component

        me.callParent();
  }
```

In initComponent(), tbar[0] get a object:

```
Object {
boxLabel: "filed label",
name: "ShowEstimationConfilictsWhileReport",
itemId: "ShowEstimationConfilictsWhileReport",
xtype: "checkbox"
}
```

How can i get checkboxfield as extjs component OR how can i convert this object to extjs component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be converted into an object after the `this.callParent()` line. Converting the configuration from objects to components is what happens in the `initComponent()` method.